# Traci traci.simulationStep() Answered with error to command 0xa4

Tags: python, sumo

```
    sim_step = 0
    while sim_step < 10:
        try:
            traci.simulationStep()
        except:
            print('1')
        drop, done, coll = self.is_done()
```

this is my code，

```
def is_done(self):
    drop = False  
    done = False
    coll = {}
    coll_list = traci.simulation.getCollidingVehiclesIDList()
    for lv_id in self.lv_topology.keys():
        pl_ids = list(self.lv_topology[lv_id])
        pl_ids.append(lv_id)
        coll[lv_id] = False
        for pl in pl_ids:
            if pl in coll_list:
                done = True
                coll[lv_id] = True
    if done:
        print('1')
        return drop, done, coll
    veh_list = traci.vehicle.getIDList()
    pl_set = set(
        vehicle_id for vehicle_id in veh_list
        if vehicle_id.startswith('pl') and vehicle_id.endswith('0'))
    lv_set = set(self.lv_topology.keys())
    if not lv_set - pl_set == set():
        drop = True
        del_id = list(lv_set - pl_set)[0]
        del self.lv_topology[del_id]
    if not pl_set - lv_set == set():
        drop = True
```

When the first vehicle in the car formation leaves the simulated road network, running traci.simulationStep() results in an error: "Answered with error to command 0xa4: Vehicle 'pl_5_0' is not known." Here, "pl_5_0" is just an example.

every time i call traci.simulationStep(), it will display this error

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've managed to resolve the issue successfully.